# Blocking collection when collect results inside ActionBlock

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I think in the test method the "results" collection variable has to be of type `BlockingCollection<int>` instead of `List<int>`. Prove it to me if I am wrong. I have taken this example from https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html

```
private static async Task Produce(BufferBlock<int> queue, IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        await queue.SendAsync(value);
    }
}

public async Task ProduceAll(BufferBlock<int> queue)
{
    var producer1 = Produce(queue, Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
    var producer2 = Produce(queue, Enumerable.Range(10, 10));
    var producer3 = Produce(queue, Enumerable.Range(20, 10));
    await Task.WhenAll(producer1, producer2, producer3);
    queue.Complete();
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task ConsumerReceivesCorrectValues()
{
    var results = new List<int>();

    // Define the mesh.
    var queue = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 5, });

    //var consumerOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1, };

    var consumer = new ActionBlock<int>(x => results.Add(x), consumerOptions);
    queue.LinkTo(consumer, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true, });

    // Start the producers.
    var producers = ProduceAll(queue);

    // Wait for everything to complete.
    await Task.WhenAll(producers, consumer.Completion);

    // Ensure the consumer got what the producer sent.
    Assert.IsTrue(results.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(Enumerable.Range(0, 30)));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `ActionBlock<T>` restricts its delegate to one-execution-at-a-time by default (`MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of `1`), it is not necessary to use `BlockingCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`.

The test in your code passes just fine for me, as expected.

If `ActionBlock<T>` were passed an option with a higher `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, then you would need to protect the `List<T>` or replace it with a `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Comment: Thank you! As I expected. Is this way of collecting data from blocks is a typical solution? Or probably It'd be better to organize Consumer Task and collect data there in one consumer scenario?                 
 `code`private static async Task<IEnumerable<int>> Consume(BufferBlock<int> queue)
{
    var ret = new List<int>();
    while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        ret.Add(await queue.ReceiveAsync());
    }

    return ret;
}`code`

Comment: @OlegIvanov: Usually, once you have a dataflow pipeline or mesh in place, your final actions become part of an `ActionBlock`. It's not common to collect all the resulting items at all, although it is occasionally done.